# jQuery - Change CSS of a single DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="cont">
    <div class="us"></div>
    <div class="us"></div>
    <div class="us"></div>
</div>
```

and this JS code:

```
$(".us").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
});
```

The problem is that the three elements are changed. I tried it without the **cont** DIV and works perfectly, just one element is changed, but I need it. Also, I tried giving single IDs to the DIVs, but keeps failing.

Comment: "Keeps failing" how, when you had ids on each `div`?

Comment: or use .eq(indexNumberofElement)

Comment: The problem isn't with the code of Jquery there most be some structure or CSS because works for me http://jsfiddle.net/6H8f4/7/

Comment: You were right. Is the `float: right;` of the **cont** DIV what make it fail. Is there any alternative to float then?

Comment: Show us your code try to replicate it in a fiddle like the link I've provide

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/6H8f4/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with your CSS code, because the `div` elements are acting like a block together you increase all the container by adding the `margin` an the other ones take the space too. You can add this to make each `div` add the margin:

```
.us {
  float:right;
  clear:right;
}
```

Your demo http://jsfiddle.net/6H8f4/14/

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways you can select one item.

```
//the first one
$(".us").first().mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
});

//the second one
$(".us").eq(1).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
});

//the third one
$(".us:nth-child(3)").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
});
```

Comment: Didn't work :( It's odd, if I give an ID to one of the three DIVs and I try with it ($("#us1") instead $(".us")) fails too.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code in it?  It may be a css issue.  I'm wondering if jquery is working, but the css makes it look like it's not?

Comment: @user2223034 the problem is not Jquery function or selector ... the problem is your structure and CSS show that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".us:first-child").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
});
```

or

```
$(".us:last-child").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
    });
```

or

```
$(".us:nth-child(index)").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/Z9rbv/) what you wanted?

```
<div id="cont">
    <div class="us">asdfafsdf</div>
    <div class="us">343464</div>
    <div class="us">asdfdsfds</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('#cont').children(".us").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
         $(this).animate({marginRight: "10px"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

made a fiddle

```
$(".us").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({'margin-right': 100}, "fast");
});

$(".us").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({'margin-right': 5}, "fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QjL9J/1/

when using animate setting ints as values will make them px by default

also css properties should be in '' in the animate object, and write the actual property (margin-right not marginRight)

and this should work, you dont manually need to create the each for the elements, its done under the hood with this.